# Groovy : datetime delta and JsonOutput.toJson

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to return some data from the database. When I call the method [`JsonOutput.toJson()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.0/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonOutput.html) with the provided data, it automatically changes the delta of my datatime.

This is my code :

```
def result = groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(data)

println(data)
println(result)

response.setContentType("application/json");
```

The first prints the following:

```
[[ DateStart:2019-01-14 09:34:51.0, DateEnd:2019-01-14 10:27:22.68]]
```

And the second after the json formatting show another date (hours - 1) :

```
[{"DateStart":"2019-01-14T08:34:51+0000","DateEnd":"2019-01-14T09:27:22+0000"}]
```

Any tips to format to JSON without changing any date/delta?

Comment: could you check the datatype of `DateStart` and `DateEnd` ? `println(data[0].DateStart.getClass())`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `data.toString()` output format:

```
[[ DateStart:2019-01-14 09:34:51.0, DateEnd:2019-01-14 10:27:22.68]]
```

it looks like you are dealing with JSON serialization of the`java.sql.Timestamp` type. If you want to prevent the default timestamp serializer from being used, you will have to format timestamps manually before JSON serialization happens.

Consider the following example:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import java.sql.Timestamp

def format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.S"
def date = new Date().parse(format, "2019-01-14T09:34:51.0")

def dateStart = new Timestamp(date.time)
def dateEnd = new Timestamp((date + 20).time)

def data = [[DateStart: dateStart, DateEnd: dateEnd]]

println "Raw data:"
println data

println "\nJSON without formatting:"
println JsonOutput.toJson(data)

data = data.collect { el -> el.collectEntries { k,v ->
    def value = v instanceof Timestamp ? v.format(format) : v
    return [(k): value]
}}

println "\nJSON after formatting:"
println JsonOutput.toJson(data)
```

The output:

```
Raw data:
[[DateStart:2019-01-14 09:34:51.0, DateEnd:2019-02-03 09:34:51.0]]

JSON without formatting:
[{"DateStart":"2019-01-14T08:34:51+0000","DateEnd":"2019-02-03T08:34:51+0000"}]

JSON after formatting:
[{"DateStart":"2019-01-14T09:34:51.0","DateEnd":"2019-02-03T09:34:51.0"}]
```

The most important part (formatting timestamp value to its string representation) happens in the following part:

```
data = data.collect { el -> el.collectEntries { k,v ->
    def value = v instanceof Timestamp ? v.format(format) : v
    return [(k): value]
}}
```

It assumes that your list of maps may contain other key-value pairs which don't hold the timestamp value. If we deal with a timestamp, we format it using `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.S` format, and we return a not-modified value otherwise.